# How to modify list to make identical to different list in Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to make two lists identical by making changes to just one of them.

For example, if L1 = [1, 2, 4, 5] and L2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], I would like to remove 2 and add 3 and 6 to L1, making it into [1, 3, 4, 5, 6] as well.

I know how to get a new list with the duplicates/differences, by iterating through them at the same time and compare elements with != but I have no idea how to start on making L1 into L2 by adding/deleting accordingly.
Can anyone help with this? I'm using python btw.

Comment: You can just do `L1[:] = L2`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're specifically trying to create a duplicate list with this approach (like for a homework assignment)? If not just use `list(L1)` which will produce an identical copy of the list. If your list contains objects make sure to make copies of those too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Won't L1 = L2 do the job?

Comment: @kingkupps yes it's for an assignment, and I actually have to do this with two input files but am trying to approach it with lists first because I'm just very very lost

Comment: @ThaerA no, that just makes the variables `L1` and `L2` refer to the same object, leaving the other list unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pop(). You just say for example:

`f l1 == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and L2 == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    l1.pop(3, 4, 7)
    L2.pop(3, 4, 7)`

and just to check it you print l1 and L2. But I will explain the pop function.
In the parenthesis you type the index of your number that you want to delete. Don't forget that the count of objects in your list starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

A={1, 2, 4, 5}

B= {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}

C=A&B

C
Out[35]: {1, 4, 5}

B-C
Out[36]: {3, 6}

C=C|(B-C)

C
Out[38]: {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}

A=C

A
Out[40]: {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
L1 = [1, 2, 4, 5] 
L2 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
L1 = [i for i in L2]
print(L1)
```